# After effects: how to make a text follow top of animated bar in bar chart

Tags: animation, expression, bar-chart, after-effects

I want to animate a horizontal bar chart. The bars (squares) start at zero and grow within two easy-ease keyframes from 0 to a specific value. This value is displayed in a text layer. I have set up a slider which goes from zero to the specific value and controls both the text layer (value) and the size of the bar (width of square).

**Problem: I want the value to follow the top of the bar chart as in here:**

https://www.instagram.com/p/B7_5SOQFrW6/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link

I tried to set easy-ease keyframes for the text layer too and adjust the values in the diagram editor. Result was too shaky and not nice to look at. Is there a solution with expressions?

source text of text layer for first Bar (1):

```
Math.round(thisComp.layer("controler").effect("1")("slider"))
```

source for square (first bar):

```
temp = thisComp.layer("controler").effect("1")("slider");
he_ = thisComp.layer("controler").effect("height")("slider");
[temp,wi_]
```

info: width is a slider with which I control the height of the bars.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample project, with both vertical and horizontal bars: https://url.io/ae_barchart

You can use `sourceRectAtTime` (like in the sample project), or calculate the position of the top side of your bar, knowing it's height and bottom Y coordinate and then translate it into Composition space from the bar layer`s space, so you can apply it to your Text Layer position.

If you check the position property of "bar_horizontal_text" / "bar_vertical_text" layers you'll see what I mean.

The rest of the setup is extra... just "fooling around". :-)